# $f:2^{\mathbb{Z}}\to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(A) = |A|$ is it surjective or injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$f:2^{\mathbb{Z}}\to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(A) = |A|$. Is it surjective or injective?

I understand that it's injective if $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2})$

and it's surjective if for every element $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is some element in $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$ so that $|A| = b$

But I don't understand at all how to solve either one.

Comment: 1) What are the images of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$? 2) Can a negative integer be in the range?

Comment: As a relation between $2^{\Bbb Z}$ and $\Bbb Z$, $f$ is neither. As a function from $2^{\Bbb Z}$ to $\Bbb Z$, $f$ is nothing.

Comment: What do you THINK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

Remember, $2^{\Bbb Z}$ is synonymous with the power set of the integers: the set of all subsets of the integers.

- For injectivity, the question you want to ask amounts to this: do there exist at least two distinct sets which share the same cardinality? If so, then the function is not injective, since there would exist sets $A,B$ such that $f(A) = f(B)$, but $A \ne B$. If you conclude two sets only have the same cardinality if they're the same set, then $f$ is injective.
- For surjectivity, consider: for every integer $n \in \Bbb Z$, can you construct some set of integers $S \subseteq \Bbb Z$ such that $|S| = n$? (This has to be true for every integer, e.g. $0,1,-1,2,-2,$ and so on.)

---

**Footnote:**

The function you describe is not well-defined. This is because $\Bbb Z$, as well as any infinite subset of it, like the odd or even integers, are in $2^{\Bbb Z}$, but there is no integer corresponding to their cardinality.

In other words, you cannot say, with this definition of $f$, what $f(\Bbb Z)$ is, for example.

This would be like defining $g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $g(x) = 1/x$ and trying to ask what $g(0)$ is, if you want a comparable example. In that case, you have to either develop a separate definition for $g(0)$ (like say $g(x) = 1/x$ for $x \ne 0$, and specify a value for $g(0)$), or just change the domain of $g$ to $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

Basically, the function $f$ you describe should be restricted to the finite subsets of $\Bbb Z$, or have its codomain expanded so that the cardinal $\aleph_0$ is included.

Of course, all of this assumes $f$ is meant to be a "total function." If $f$ is permitted to be a "partial function" -- i.e.  you don't have to define a $y \in \text{cod}(f)$ such that, for all $x\in \text{dom}(f)$, $f(x)=y$ -- this is fine. I feel like that $f$ being a partial function is not the intent though.

Comment: @Evee Trainer So, it would be injective because there are lots of sets within $2^{Z}$ that share the same cardinality? And it's NOT surjectivity because Z includes negative numbers, and it's impossible to contruct sets with cardinality of a negative value?

Comment: It would **not** be injective for the reason you stated: my wording was somewhat unclear in that respect. And correct, that would be why $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I had actually just figured out that it was neither but wasn't able to edit my comment after 5 mins. Thanks so much for your help! Much more understandable now